# Android - can't get header layout to lign up

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this header:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip">    

 <Button android:id="@+id/home"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Home"
/>

 <Button android:id="@+id/questions"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="My Questions"
 /> 

<Button android:id="@+id/questions"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Questions"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"  />  


 <Button android:id="@+id/businesses"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Businesses"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/businesses"
 />  

 <Button android:id="@+id/learn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Learn"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/learn"
 />  


 <Button android:id="@+id/extra_help"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Help"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/learn"
/>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

and for some reason, the buttons display 50% on top of each other all bunched up, each covering half of the other.

Any idea what is wrong with my layout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative layout, you need to manage both horizontal and vertical alignment. For example, all the android:layout_toRightOf are used for horizontal positioning, you need to also add attributes to handle the vertical positioning.

All the possible attributes are found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

**UPDATE**
Seeing your comments below, it seems you just want to have one horizontal row. In that case, just make sure each is aligned to the previous one(But then why not use a linear layout?)

Check your id's though, and @+id/learn is aligned to the right of itself. Revisit that. And you also have a button right after "Home" that isn't handled at all.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  How should I do it? You don't mean specifying the actual pixel sizes, do you?

Comment: @JustDanyl thanks, browsing it now...since you mentioned it, I am not sure where the layout_below will be useful. What should be done with it? Seems I need to_the_side rather than below :)

Comment: I might have misunderstood the layout you are trying to create, but you said they where bunched on top of each other, if you want them all on ONE line then yes, you only need to concern yourself with the horizontal placement. Notice though, you have two elements with the same ID. In your layout, I suspect "My Questions" will be placed exactly the same place (on top) of "home"